# Is there any way to use a custom font with moderncv?

Tags: fonts, moderncv, sharelatex

The package `moderncv` proposes only two available options for the font selection `roman` & `sans`. I've seen the following declaration in the source code of the package:

```
\DeclareOption{sans}{\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}}}
```

Are there any tricks around to overload this inside a .tex file in order to load another font ?

Comment: You can use `xelatex` of course. Or use some other font like `libertine` → `\usepackage{libertine}`

Comment: The declaration doesn't change the font; it only changes the family of the font to be sans serif, but the font will be the same previously loaded.

Comment: @HarishKumar I've thought of using xelatex and using a ttf font but I'm using sharelatex and when I'm changing the compilation type and recompiling I get a lot of errors, it seems that the package they're using is not really up to date.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina , so it means that I cannot change the font afterwards as it is loaded by the package itself beforehand.

Comment: Font ant family have different meanings. Font is like say `Times New Roman` and family can be `roman` or `sans serif`. What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: Of course you can use different fonts; either T1 fonts (loaded with `\usepackage`) with pdflatex, or TrueType fonts useing xelatex.

Comment: With: `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cyklop}` the font is not loaded and it falls back to the default sans-serif font.

Comment: As long as the `cyklop` T1 font is installed in your system, you can use it without problems. If not, you'll need to install it.

Comment: OH My... Do you plan to use `cyklop` font for your CV? You must be kidding :)

Comment: Of course I won't use `cyklop` :) I was messing around with the font settings and I wanted one that was really different from the base one in order to see if my tweaks had really an effect.

Comment: `cyklop` only affects the default *serif* font. So you have loaded it for serif but then told `moderncv` to use sans which is still the default sans. Tell `moderncv` to use `roman` rather than `sans` or pick a font package which redefines the *sans* family.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, here is an example of `libertine` CV. Change `sans to rmfamily if you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{libertine}    %% or newtxtext for times 
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}

\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `xelatex`, options are unlimited. Adding

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Calibri}    %% change to any available .ttf or .otf font
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{libertine}    %% or newtxtext for times
```

and compiling with `xelatex`, gives

[image]

Comment: I am not so sure about sharelatex, they seem to be using old texlive some how.