# Unable to change font with ModernCV

Tags: fonts, luatex, moderncv

I've been trying to change the font with modernCV for quite a while now, but nothing seems to work. I'm using LuaTex. To start with, I tried changing it from sans to roman, although the font changes, you can see that nothing is being italicized or bolded as it should be.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}  

\moderncvicons{awesome}%marvosym  

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % casual/classic/oldstyle/banking/fancy
\moderncvcolor{green}                              % blue/orange/green/red/purple/grey/black

\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{First}{Last}                               
\address{Address}{City}{Country}
\phone[mobile]{123456}                  
\email{abc@gmail.com}                                

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
%==============================================================================================================================
% EXPERIENCE
%==============================================================================================================================
\section{Experience}

\cventry{May 2015 -- July 2015}{Intern Research Assistant}{Institute of Whatever}{XXX, YYY}{Supervisor: Dr. ABC}{{}
\vspace{4pt}
\begin{itemize}%
\item Nice stuff.
\end{itemize}}
\vspace{7pt}


\end{document}
```

[image: This is how it is when it says sans on line 1.]
[image: This is how it looks when I switch it to roman (as it is in the MWE)]

First image is how it looks with sans on line 1, and second is how it looks with roman. Nothing is in bold or italics as you can see.

Afterwards, I tried multiple methods to change the font, all of them did absolutely nothing:

1. I tried the two answers here:
   [Change font used by moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31534/change-font-used-by-moderncv)

   `\documentclass{moderncv}
   \usepackage{mathpazo}
   \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}`
2. The answer here with xelatex: 
   [Is there any way to use a custom font with moderncv?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164479/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-custom-font-with-moderncv)

   `\usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Calibri}`
3. I tried the answer here as well, as this was my main goal: [Change body font in moderncv without affecting the other fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49831/change-body-font-in-moderncv-without-affecting-the-other-fonts)

My original goal was to remove the italics from fields 1, 2 and 5 from CV entry (date, position and supervisor/extra info). None of those worked.

With the MWE provided on answer 3, some stuff worked but some didn't. For example, I could change the font size of the title but I could not do a single thing for the hint font, it would never change.

I would appreciate any help.

EDIT: 
Clarification: my original problem involves

1. Changing the whole document's font (solved, see below).
2. Changing the font in fields 1, 2 and 5 of the `cventry` command.

Following @Ulrike Fischer's comment, I added
`\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` after `\moderncvstyle{banking}` and the first issue has been fixed. Now I get a roman font where things are italicized and bolded as they should be. 
However, if I add `\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{\upshape}`, the font for the dates stays in Italics. I cannot change its size with `\renewcommand*\hintfont{\fontsize{40}{24}}` either, and I have no idea how to change fields 2 and 5 to non-italic.

Edit: As noted in the comments, the way to fix this is to add \upshape before specific fields, preferably with a wrapper for cventry. Redefining does not work for me.

Comment: The banking-style is not adapted to lualatex, it loads an unsuitable font. Add `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` (or some other font) *after* loading banking. Beside this your question is rather unclear and linking to lots of other answers doesn't help much. Do you want to change the overall font or only the look of some elements?

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify things. I want to do both, I first wanted to change the font of the whole document (your comment fixed that, thank you), then I want to change some fields to not be italics (date, position name, last field of CV entry). This I still cannot fix.

Comment: The \itshape is hardcoded in cventry (in moderncvbodyiii.sty).

Comment: Is there any other way to change it from italics? It seems to have worked for people but the answers are old and the package was just updated again last month.

Comment: You can copy the definition and redefine the command. Or write some wrapper command that does `\cventry{\upshape May 2015 -- July 2015}...`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Wanna write an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As asked in the comments I convert my comments to a (short) answer:

The banking-style is not adapted to lualatex, it loads an unsuitable font. So to change the document font add `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` (or some other font) *after* loading banking.

The `\itshape` is hardcoded in cventry (in moderncvbodyiii.sty). To change this you will have to add `\upshape` directly in the entries, e.g. `\cventry{\upshape May 2015 -- July 2015}`, or write some wrapper command.

Comment: I love seeing old questions answered.